# Concatenate loop and string input to form a column name in R

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse

I would like to loop through a series of linear probability models. As a proxy for my own data, I'll recreate the context using the `iris` data set.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fastDummies)
data(iris)

iris <- iris %>% 
  dummy_cols("Species")

names(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length"       "Sepal.Width"        "Petal.Length"       "Petal.Width"        "Species"           
[6] "Species_setosa"     "Species_versicolor" "Species_virginica"
```

In this example, I begin by loading the data and then specifying two independent linear probability models comparing either "versicolor" or "virginica" to "setosa" as my reference level. These models are easy to run independently.

```
# model 1
iris %>%
  filter(Species %in% c("setosa", "versicolor")) %$%
  lm(Species_versicolor ~ Sepal.Length, data = .)

Call:
lm(formula = Species_versicolor ~ Sepal.Length, data = .)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  Sepal.Length  
     -2.6203        0.5703  

# model 2
iris %>%
  filter(Species %in% c("setosa", "virginica")) %$%
  lm(Species_virginica ~ Sepal.Length, data = .)

Call:
lm(formula = Species_virginica ~ Sepal.Length, data = .)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  Sepal.Length  
      -2.092         0.447
```

But, I would like to expedite the process and loop through the species levels. Here is an example of what I am imagining for the process.

```
for (i in c("versicolor", "virginica")) {
  model <- iris %>%
    filter(Species %in% c("setosa", i)) %$%
    lm(paste0("Species_", i) ~ Sepal.Length, data = .)
}
```

The problem with this code is that `lm` is not recognizing the result of the `paste0` function as a column name and provides the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = paste0("Species_", i) ~ Sepal.Length,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Sepal.Length')
```

Is there a way to concatenate loop and string data to form a column name in R that would be recognizable by `lm`? Or, is there a feasible workaround that doesn't dramatically change the format of the original models?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. It would be `fastDummies::dummy_cols`. I've updated the post to include the package.

Comment: Can you  please check the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `formula` is not complete.  Using `tidyverse` functions, the output will return in a `list` while looping with `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
lst1 <- map(c("versicolor", "virginica"), ~
          iris %>%
            filter(Species %in% c("setosa", .x)) %>%  
             lm(reformulate("Sepal.Length", 
                  response = str_c("Species_", .x)), data = .))
```

---

If we use a `for` loop, make sure to assign the output to a `list` created

```
lst2 <- vector('list', 2)
names(lst2) <- c("versicolor", "virginica")
for (val in names(lst2)) {
   lst2[[val]] <- iris %>%
        filter(Species %in% c("setosa", val)) %>%
         lm(as.formula(paste0("Species_", val, " ~ Sepal.Length")), data = .)
    }

lst2
#$versicolor

#Call:
#lm(formula = as.formula(paste0("Species_", val, " ~ Sepal.Length")), 
#   data = .)



#Coefficients:
# (Intercept)  Sepal.Length  
#     -2.6203        0.5703  


#$virginica

#Call:
#lm(formula = as.formula(paste0("Species_", val, " ~ Sepal.Length")), 
#   data = .)



#Coefficients:
# (Intercept)  Sepal.Length  
#      -2.092         0.447
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't apply this answer to my own situation outside of `iris` because my model formula is more complicated and has numeric values that cannot be included as part of a grand string covering the entire formula.

Comment: @Craig It is based on your example showed.  If it is different, then please update your post as i am not sure what kinid of model you are creating

Comment: It doesn't fit situations outside of this one where more complicated formula specifications apply and it dramatically alters the specification of the model by making the entire formula a string.

Comment: @Craig  are you talking about `glm`

Comment: I am using `lfe::felm` but it works similarly to `lm` or `glm` as far as the formula specification is concerned. But, what would be your workaround for a case where the formula cannot be contained as a single string?

Comment: `lfe::felm(Species_versicolor ~ Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width | 0 | Sepal.Width, data = data)`. In this example, there are characters and values that do not register if contained within a string. The only part that should be dynamic is the outcome variable.

Comment: Can't you create `paste("Species_versicolor ~ ", "Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width | 0 | Sepal.Width")`

Comment: No, that does not work because of the `|` and `0` operators. If I try to do that then I get the following error: `Error in new.env(parent = formenv) : use of NULL environment is defunct`.

Comment: Can you convert to formula with `as.formula`

Comment: Yes! That makes it work. Using `as.formula` makes your solution generalize to more complicated model formulas and fits my real world situation that is not captured by my example here. If you add `as.formula` to your answer then I will accept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207212/discussion-between-craig-and-akrun).